# How to find the generators of a principal Ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$ and $I = \{0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21\}$.

$I$ is a principal ideal.

Is there a method to find ALL the generators ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hands-on approach:* We know that the order of $a\in G$ an element equals the order of the ideal it generates.
In this case, $|I| = 8$, so $I = (a) \iff n\cdot a\bmod 24 \neq 0$ for $n = 1,\dots,7$.

Since elements of $I$ are of the form $m\cdot 3$, this is looking for $m = 1,\dots,7$ such that $n\cdot m \bmod 8 \neq 0$ for $n = 1,\dots,7$:

$$n\cdot m \bmod 8 = 0 \iff (n,m) \in \{(4,2),(2,4),(4,4),(6,4),(4,6)\}$$

So $6,12,18$ *don't* generate $I$, and $3,9,15,21$ generate it.